# get the fullname of a each user in the roster openfire xmpp strophe

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

This will query all the list of contacts in my roster,but it only allows me to query the JID and not the fullname. How do I query the roster and get each name?

```
$(document).bind('connected', function(){
   var iq = $iq({type: 'get'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'});
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var iq = $iq({type: 'get'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'});
conn.sendIQ(iq,
            function success(iq){
                $(iq).find('item').each(function () { //all contacts 
                    var jid = $(this).attr('jid');
                    var name = $(this).attr('name') || jid;
                    var subscr = $(this).attr('subscription'); //type subscription
                    console.log('contacts: jid:' + jid + '  Name:' + name);
                });
            },
            function failure(iq){
                console.log(iq);
            },30000/*timeout sendIQ*/
        );
```

Also you can mix with

```
<iq from='userroster@jabber.org'
    id='v1'
    type='get'>
  <vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/>
</iq>
```

To get vcard's of each user and then get full name.

Try it.

Comment: yeah but how do i translate that in Strophe way?

Comment: By query jid is not possible, another solution, if you want to get full is when you add/update your roster you can set the name as full name, this way:

var contact = {jid: 'me@jabber.org', name: 'My Full Name'};
var iq = $iq({type: 'set'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'}).c('item', {jid: contact.jid, name: contact.name});

Comment: But when i request a roster name not come for every item.
I have found this on roster.

<item jid="sat4@canopus30" subscription="from"></item>
<item jid="sat2@canopus30" subscription="both"></item>
<item jid="sat@canopus30" name="sat" subscription="from">
<group>Friends</group>
</item>
<item jid="sat3@canopus30" subscription="both"></item>
<item jid="null@canopus30" ask="subscribe" subscription="none"></item>